# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have a Json Model Schema from a third party API that looks like this:

```
    {
  "Entries": [
    {
      "Id": "",
      "RowId": 0,
      "FormId": "",
      "FormExternalId": "",
      "FormVersion": 0,
      "DeviceId": "",
      "UserFirstName": "",
      "UserLastName": "",
      "UserEmail": "",
      "UserExternalId": "",
      "Latitude": 0,
      "Longitude": 0,
      "StartTime": "Date",
      "CompleteTime": "Date",
      "ReceivedTime": "Date",
      "AnswerFormat": "",
      "Answers": [
        {
          "Name": "",
          "Type": "",
          "Value": "",
          "Answers": [
            "Answer_GET_"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "AnswersFlat": "Array[AnswerSet]",
      "AnswersFlatXml": "XML",
      "AnswersRawXml": "XML",
      "AnswersRawJson": "JSON",
      "TaskId": "",
      "DSRowId": "",
      "MediaAsUrl": false,
      "Fields": "",
      "PurgeDays": 0,
      "CompanyId": 0
    }
  ],
  "TotalRows": 0,
  "ResponseStatus": {
    "ErrorCode": "",
    "Message": "",
    "Errors": [
      {
        "ErrorCode": "",
        "FieldName": "",
        "Message": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I made a class for this in Visual Studio that looks like this:

```
class form_results
    {

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public Entry[] Entries { get; set; }
            public int TotalRows { get; set; }
            public Responsestatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
        }

        public class Responsestatus
        {
            public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
            public Error[] Errors { get; set; }
        }

        public class Error
        {
            public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
            public string FieldName { get; set; }
            public string Message { get; set; }
        }

        public class Entry
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public int RowId { get; set; }
            public string FormId { get; set; }
            public string FormExternalId { get; set; }
            public int FormVersion { get; set; }
            public string DeviceId { get; set; }
            public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
            public string UserLastName { get; set; }
            public string UserEmail { get; set; }
            public string UserExternalId { get; set; }
            public float Latitude { get; set; }
            public float Longitude { get; set; }
            public string StartTime { get; set; }
            public string CompleteTime { get; set; }
            public string ReceivedTime { get; set; }
            public string AnswerFormat { get; set; }
            public Answer[] Answers { get; set; }
            public string AnswersFlat { get; set; }
            public string AnswersFlatXml { get; set; }
            public string AnswersRawXml { get; set; }
            public string AnswersRawJson { get; set; }
            public string TaskId { get; set; }
            public string DSRowId { get; set; }
            public bool MediaAsUrl { get; set; }
            public string Fields { get; set; }
            public int PurgeDays { get; set; }
            public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        }

        public class Answer
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string[] Answers { get; set; }
        }

    }
```

When I try to deserialize the json with the following command:

```
var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<form_results.Rootobject>(json);
```

I'm geting the error "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Entries[0].Answers[0].Answers', line 25, position 25.'"

That part of the Json string looks like this:

```
     {... more json results...
"AnswerFormat": "Rich",
        "Answers": [{
            "Name": "Page 1",
            "Type": "Group",
            "Answers": [{
                    "Name": "Value 1",
                    "Type": "SelectOne"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Value 2",
                    "Type": "SelectOne"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }

]
```

The Json is valid, so that is not the problem. As far as I can see the problem occurs at the array section of the Json file.

Also tried `var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<form_results.Rootobject>>(json);` but gave also an error.

What I want is the results (answers) from the Answers array.

Comment: I would start by ignoring your data model - can you parse it as a `JObject`? If so, you know that the problem is in the JSON instead, and you can provide a [mcve] showing a *complete* JSON file and program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Answer class is declared like this

```
public class Answer
{
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public string[] Answers { get; set; }
}
```

This includes an `array` of `string` called `Answers`

But in your JSON, this array is an array of objects (Extract below)

```
"Answers": [{
                    "Name": "Value 1",
                    "Type": "SelectOne"
                },
                {
                    "Name": "Value 2",
                    "Type": "SelectOne"
                }
            ]
```

So you need to change your class to match this JSON.  Maybe like this

```
public class Answer
{
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public SubAnswer[] Answers { get; set; }
}

public class SubAnswer
{
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Or you could maybe use the Composite pattern, if you want Answer and SubAnswer to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the class `answers` can contain further `answer`s thats why you can modify your Answer class like following:

```cs
 public class Answer
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Type { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        }
```